# Excel power query not loading Salesforce report

Tags: reporting, query, excel

I am having issues loading a Salesforce report into Excel through Power Query. I currently have several reports all successfully loading, however with this specific report Excel is not loading anything. This particular report is a historical trending type report in Salesforce which may have something to do with it. This is a new issue that just started in the past week or two as I have never had problems loading any of my reports. Perhaps some update to either Excel or Salesforce I am missing?

I've attached a screenshot of the query preview. As you can see, I am not getting an error message, just a blank table.

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you click 'Edit' and then "Refresh Preview' on the next screen?

Comment: Hi Sequoyah. I get the same result. All I get is a message saying "This table is empty".

Comment: @Sequoyah tagging you

Comment: Few more questions: 1. Have you confirmed that the report does return results when you run it directly within Salesforce? 2. What version of Excel are you running (exact version and build number)? 3. Has the report been altered in any way since the last time it worked? 4. What object(s) does the report use? 5. Have there been any recent changes in Salesforce that could affect record visibility (user roles, record ownership, etc)? 6. Are you accessing it through PowerQuery with the same user account that you'd use to log into SF directly?

Comment: 1. Yes the report runs in Salesforce.                                                                    2. Excel 2016. I also just re-installed it.                                                                           3. No

Comment: 4. The report is an Opportunity History report and uses the Opportunity object                                                                                                                        5. Not that I am aware of                                                                                   6. Yes. I have several other reports that are being pulled through Power Query successfully, but with this specific report it is coming up blank

Comment: The report type is actually Opportunities with Historical Trending

Comment: Weird. Only similar thing I’ve seen involved a custom geolocation field, but that issue was fixed in an Excel update in mid-2017. Have you tested a new report of the same type, with just the default fields and filters set to show opps from all owners/dates? If that works, it suggests that the issue is related to some filter or field that Excel doesn’t like for some reason. From there, you'd just add in fields and filters until the new report is an exact copy of the old one, periodically testing in Excel to see where it breaks. Should at least provide a clue about what the problem might be.

Comment: Yeah I ended up recreating the report from scratch in Salesforce and it seems to be connecting now. Must have been some filter or formatting that was causing the issue. Weird since I hadn't changed the report at all. Thanks for the assist